# Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',)

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsxwriter

I am trying to put a bunch of CSV files into one workbook and here is my code:

```
import csv
import glob
import openpyxl
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter as xlwr

def main():

    list_of_files = []
    names = []
    for csv_file in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
        bleh = csv_file[2:]
        name = bleh[:-4]
        names.append(name)
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, index_col=None, header=0)
        list_of_files.append(df)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('non_concussed_game_logs.xlsx')
    for n, df in enumerate(list_of_files):
        df.to_excel(writer, '%s' % names[n])
    writer.save


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting the error mentioned in the title of my post but I am unsure as to why I'm getting it. I have used this script before and it has worked but I'm not sure why it is not now. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `writer.save` doesn't call the method.

Comment: That is an exception that can be raised by a number of issues further up the stack. It isn't possible to tell what the issue is from that one line. Add the full stack trace. Also it probably should be `save()` as a method (with parentheses).

Comment: thank you both for the responses but I figured it out, all the CSV files were encoded in utf-8 and I just had to add that into the read_csv call... and also make it writer.save() lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, my CSV files were encoded in `utf-8` so I had to make the `read_csv()` call

`df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, index_col=None, header=0, encoding='utf-8')`

and also add the parenthesis to the `writer.save` line.